# JMeter variable in GET request failing

Tags: apache, variables, get, jmeter, request

I have a GET Request that is returning an XML that contains a TicketName. I have setup the Regular Expression Extractor with Debug Sampler. It is picking up the TicketName as required and is displaying it in the View Results Tree, with the correct name variable name ticketID_g1. 
However when I pass that variable to the next GET request the test plan fails with Non HTTP response message: Socket closed.
The thing is that the GET request looks find when I look at the request tab in the Results Tree.

I have changed my regular expression a number of times with each one extracting the TicketName properly but each time I apply it as a variable the GET request fails. However if I copy the request showing in the Results Tree Request Tab and paste it directly into my browser I get the desired result.

I have been through the manuals and on-line tutorials and it appears that I am doing everything right but obviously I am missing something.

The 1st GET Request returns an XML that contains name="2019-05-09-16-59-54cmrpip000613_EDASERVE" needsPrompt

I am using the following regular expression to extract the name for my variable ticketID

name="([^"]+)" needsPrompt - This works

The Results Tree is showing the following response from the Debug Sampler -

ticketID_g1=2019-05-09-16-59-54cmrpip000613_EDASERVE

When I pass the ticketID variable to the next GET request

//localhost:8080/ibi_apps/rs?IBIRS_action=getReport&IBIRS_ticketName=${ticketID_g1}cmrpip000589_EDASERVE&IBIRS_service=defer

The Response tab in the Results Tree for the second GET request is showing that the request is good but is failing.

GET http://localhost:8080/ibi_apps/rs?IBIRS_action=getReport&IBIRS_ticketName=2019-05-09-16-59-54cmrpip000613_EDASERVE&IBIRS_service=defer

What I am expecting is that this second GET will run with the variable and return a report but is throwing the Non HTTP response message: Socket closed error.

Answer (score 0):

You have below variable which is capturing ticket id.

**ticketID_g1**=2019-05-09-16-59-54**cmrpip000613_EDASERVE**

But, in the below request you are passing the same which also have repeated content that is 
"cmrpip000589_EDASERVE"

Request:-//localhost:8080/ibi_apps/rs?IBIRS_action=getReport&IBIRS_ticketName=${**ticketID_g1**}**cmrpip000589_EDASERVE**&IBIRS_service=defer

Please pass the ticketID variable correctly and hopefully it solves the issue. If I am correct you request should look like:-

Request:-//localhost:8080/ibi_apps/rs?IBIRS_action=getReport&IBIRS_ticketName=${**ticketID_g1**}&IBIRS_service=defer

Comment: Sorry, That was my mistake in the post. I actually do have it as http://localhost:8080/ibi_apps/rs?IBIRS_action=getReport&IBIRS_ticketName=${ticketID_g1}&IBIRS_service=defer. and this fails. though the request shows as GET http://localhost:8080/ibi_apps/rs?IBIRS_action=getReport&IBIRS_ticketName=2019-05-10-08-47-44cmrpip000617_EDASERVE&IBIRS_service=defer

Comment: No problem, please share jmeter log, request and response header from view result tree. It will help others to respond faster to your issue.

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to add a constant timer of around 1 second which has resolved the issue.

Comment: Glad to hear that:)